# Get data from 2 tables in a select

Tags: php, sql, relationship

I have problem to make a relationship in 2 tables.
I have a table with User data and another with a list of friends, and would like to do a select that returns the user data and all the friends in array.
Already tried `INNER JOIN` returns but not as you like.

```
table.user
id | name | age
1  | John | 20

table.user_friend
id | user | friend
1  | 1    | friend A
2  | 1    | friend B
```

**expected**

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
         (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John
         )
    [1] => Array
         (
            [id] => 1
            [user] => 1
            [friend] => friend A
         )
    [2] => Array
         (
            [id] => 1
            [user] => 1
            [friend] => friend B
         )
 )
```

Comment: What reason for my question be negative? I have real doubts and do not know to solve. Let me know if here is not the right place to ask for help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not work with "arrays," at least not per the SQL standard. You will need to query and join, which will return one row per friend, then map the query result into a data structure of your choosing within your programming language.

Comment: I will need to do 2 selects? `select from user` and `select from friends where user = user_id`? inner join does not work for this case?

Comment: No, you could easily do a single select and retrieve all of the information in both tables (although you'd have repeated information for the users table).  Something like `SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN friends ON friends.user = user.id`.  You'll end up with a wide relation being returned. Parse that out into a structure that you like.

Comment: in this example it returns all columns of the table friend? if I have `friend.name` will collide with `user.name`, right? how can I avoid these collisions? thank you

Comment: Depending on which database you're using, they may come back with column names that include the table already; if not, you can also manually specify and distinguish them.

Comment: could use `UNION` to this case in order to return all 3 items as the example?

Comment: `UNION` will only join two relations together, it will not make them nested. SQL doesn't *do* nested.